# $wpdb->prepare placeholders %d %s , working, but I am not convinced I have done it the best

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, prepare

I have managed after a struggle to understand what is happening with the prepare placeholders. My only thought is that my table does not have a consistent element in it that I can use as a reference with the place holder.

There is a test column that I have used, but i do not intend on having it in my production plugin. The column is set to 0 for each entry, and I set the $test to 0. Thus my query has now started working. But this doesn't really make sense as a security feature unless it is dynamically calling something in reference to the results on the database. The examples I have seen around all rely on a set constant in their query, but I haven't got this unless I just add a constant entry in the database, but this seems silly.

```
$test = 0;
$result = 
$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare
    ( "SELECT * FROM $my_noted_table_name WHERE id_can_view = %d ", $test));
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain what is happening.

The `prepare` is sanitizing the variable's value, inserting it where you specified the placeholder, and then formatting the SQL query.  Then the returned SQL query string is processed by the `$wpdb->get_results()`.

### Step 1:

For this line of code:

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $my_noted_table_name WHERE id_can_view = %d", $test );
```

here's what is happening:

1. Sanitizes the variable's value `$test`
2. Replaces out the placeholder with the sanitized variable's value.
3. The database table name is extracted from your `$my_noted_table_name` variable.
4. Formats the SQL query

For the placeholder, `%d` means the value will be an integer.  If it's a string, then use `%s` instead.  Think about it in terms of using the PHP construct [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or `printf`.

> d - the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as a (signed) decimal number.
>
> s - the argument is treated as and presented as a string.

So, let's say your variable `$test` has a value of 100 assigned to it and the database table's name is `countries`.  Then SQL query string then is:

```
"SELECT * FROM `countries` WHERE `id_can_view` = 100;"
```

See how `$wpdb->prepare` transformed your inputted string into a properly formatted SQL query?

You want to ALWAYS use `$wpdb->prepare()` to handle this process as it will protect your database.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your clear overview, and you have covered nicely what I have managed to just about get a grip on, yet the confusion I have is to set the value of `$test` to 100 which then is  representing "what" in the database. eg: what relevance does the 100 now have to the database? I get the impression that this needs to have some relevance to something. if id_can_view doesn't = 100 then the result get ignored, but I want all results from each row of the table, and I get the impression I will need to create an false column with 100 in each row. This seems confusing to be true to me.

Comment: Yes. SQL -> WHERE is a filter that lets you select datasets only IF the column has a value of 100.  So in this use case, the column you have as `id_can_view`.  Each record in the database table that has its column `id_can_view` with a value of 100 will be pulled and returned back to you.

Comment: When the column is <> (not equal) 100, then it is ignored and not pulled into the returned dataset.  You will want to learn SQL in order to understand what is happening with each SQL query.

Comment: So as I am not filtering anything in my query, I need to add some additional dummy data for the placeholders in this case it seems. I think this is what was causing me the confusion as I thought there would be a better system to consider when there isn't a WHERE filter. Thanks for your help.